# Return Tibble as Json

Tags: r, json, tibble

I am new to R and I am trying to use the Hansard Library.

Is there any way I could export the results of any of the queries as Json rather than a tibble?

```
library(hansard)
library(tibble)

#example query
z <- mp_vote_record(172, "aye", start_date = "2017-01-01", end_date = "2017-05-03")

print(z)
```

Giving the output:

```
# A tibble: 38 x 5
   about  title       uin    date_value          date_datatype
   <chr>  <chr>       <chr>  <dttm>              <chr>        
 1 722300 Early Parl~ CD:20~ 2017-04-19 00:00:00 POSIXct      
 2 714865 Pension Sc~ CD:20~ 2017-03-29 00:00:00 POSIXct      
 3 714866 Pension Sc~ CD:20~ 2017-03-29 00:00:00 POSIXct      
 4 714868 Pension Sc~ CD:20~ 2017-03-29 00:00:00 POSIXct      
 5 713962 Bus Servic~ CD:20~ 2017-03-27 00:00:00 POSIXct      
 6 713963 Bus Servic~ CD:20~ 2017-03-27 00:00:00 POSIXct      
 7 714005 Bus Servic~ CD:20~ 2017-03-27 00:00:00 POSIXct      
 8 710264 Reproducti~ CD:20~ 2017-03-13 00:00:00 POSIXct      
 9 708770 Children a~ CD:20~ 2017-03-07 00:00:00 POSIXct      
10 708773 Children a~ CD:20~ 2017-03-07 00:00:00 POSIXct      
# ... with 28 more rows
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just transform the `tibble` into `json` using `jsonlite` package. An example using the built-in data set iris:

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

mydata <- as_tibble(iris)
toJSON(mydata)
```

Comment: Very happy to help!